# How to get new uploaded file name in controller?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

1.Can anyone suggest me how to get new uploaded file name in controller action? I'm using validation rule like..

```
'validators' => [
                   [
                    'name' => '\User\Validator\ImageValidator',
                      'options' => [
                        'minSize' => '1',
                        'maxSize' => '1024',
                        'newFileName' => time() . 'newFileName2',
                        'uploadPath' => getcwd() . '/public/uploads/platform/'
                      ],
                   ],              
                ],
```

and it's working properly but I have no idea to how to get file name or error in controller action.

2. How to overwrite the **minSize** and **maxSize** *error message*? My validator file code is:

namespace User\Validator;

```
use Zend\Validator\File\Extension;
use Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http;
use Zend\Validator\File\FilesSize;
use Zend\Filter\File\Rename;
use Zend\Validator\File\MimeType;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class ImageValidator extends AbstractValidator
{  
    const FILE_EXTENSION_ERROR  = 'invalidFileExtention';
    const FILE_NAME_ERROR       = 'invalidFileName'; 
    const FILE_INVALID          = 'invalidFile'; 
    const FALSE_EXTENSION       = 'fileExtensionFalse';
    const NOT_FOUND             = 'fileExtensionNotFound';
    const TOO_BIG               = 'fileFilesSizeTooBig';
    const TOO_SMALL             = 'fileFilesSizeTooSmall';
    const NOT_READABLE          = 'fileFilesSizeNotReadable';

    public $minSize = 64;               //KB
    public $maxSize = 1024;             //KB
    public $overwrite = true;
    public $newFileName = null;
    public $uploadPath = './data/';
    public $extensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');
    public $mimeTypes = array(
                            'image/gif',
                            'image/jpg',
                            'image/png',
                        );

    protected $messageTemplates = array(   
            self::FILE_EXTENSION_ERROR  => "File extension is not correct", 
            self::FILE_NAME_ERROR       => "File name is not correct",  
            self::FILE_INVALID          => "File is not valid", 
            self::FALSE_EXTENSION       => "File has an incorrect extension",
            self::NOT_FOUND             => "File is not readable or does not exist", 
            self::TOO_BIG               => "// want to overwrite these message",
            self::TOO_SMALL             => "// want to overwrite these message",
            self::NOT_READABLE          => "One or more files can not be read", 
    );

    protected $fileAdapter;

    protected $validators;

    protected $filters;

    public function __construct($options)
    {
        $this->fileAdapter = new Http();  
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function isValid($fileInput)
    { 
        $options = $this->getOptions(); 
        $extensions = $this->extensions;
        $minSize    = $this->minSize; 
        $maxSize    = $this->maxSize; 
        $newFileName = $this->newFileName;
        $uploadPath = $this->uploadPath;
        $overwrite = $this->overwrite;

        if (array_key_exists('extensions', $options)) {
            $extensions = $options['extensions'];
        } 

        if (array_key_exists('minSize', $options)) {
            $minSize = $options['minSize'];
        }

        if (array_key_exists('maxSize', $options)) {
            $maxSize = $options['maxSize'];
        } 

        if (array_key_exists('newFileName', $options)) {
            $newFileName = $options['newFileName'];
        } 

        if (array_key_exists('uploadPath', $options)) {
            $uploadPath = $options['uploadPath'];
        } 

        if (array_key_exists('overwrite', $options)) {
            $overwrite = $options['overwrite'];
        }    

        $fileName   = $fileInput['name']; 
        $fileSizeOptions = null;

        if ($minSize) {
            $fileSizeOptions['min'] = $minSize*1024 ;
        }

        if ($maxSize) {
            $fileSizeOptions['max'] = $maxSize*1024 ;
        }

        if ($fileSizeOptions) {
            $this->validators[] = new FilesSize($fileSizeOptions); 
        }

        $this->validators[] = new Extension(array('extension' => $extensions));
        if (! preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-_]+[a-z0-9-_\.]+$/i', $fileName)) {
            $this->error(self::FILE_NAME_ERROR);
            return false; 
        }

        $extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        if (! in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
            $this->error(self::FILE_EXTENSION_ERROR);
            return false; 
        }

        if ($newFileName) {
            $destination = $newFileName.".$extension";
            if (! preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-_]+[a-z0-9-_\.]+$/i', $destination)) {
                $this->error(self::FILE_NAME_ERROR);
                return false;  
            }
        } else {
            $destination = $fileName;
        } 

        $renameOptions['target'] = $uploadPath.$destination;
        $renameOptions['overwrite'] = $overwrite;
        $this->filters[] = new Rename($renameOptions); 
        $this->fileAdapter->setFilters($this->filters);
        $this->fileAdapter->setValidators($this->validators); 

        if ($this->fileAdapter->isValid()) { 
            $this->fileAdapter->receive();
            return true;

        } else {   
            $messages = $this->fileAdapter->getMessages();

            if ($messages) {
                $this->setMessages($messages);
                foreach ($messages as $key => $value) { 
                    $this->error($key);
                }
            } else {
                $this->error(self::FILE_INVALID);
            }
            return false;
        }
    } 

}
```

I'm new to Zend framework so unable to understand how this validator code is working.

Thank you

Comment: For file upload there is a special `FileInput` class that can help you to get filtering and validation setup correctly. Check [the ZF2 documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html) here or check [one of many hits on Google](https://www.google.se/search?q=fileinput%20zf2)

Comment: Here is another nice example for you on file upload: https://gist.github.com/cgmartin/3797983

Comment: @Wilt Thank you! It was a real time-saver. Can you suggest when we should use controller plugin and services in zend framework 2?